# I want to use Stormpath, Express.js, and Node.js. Do I want stormpath-express or express-stormpath?

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath, express-stormpath, stormpath-express

I posted an earlier question ("[What do I need to know to transfer a working Node project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319150/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-transfer-a-working-node-project?noredirect=1#comment52519790_32319150)") after I had a Node project working on a server, and couldn't get it to work at all on my laptop.

In the course of drafting another comment, I noticed something funny. The person who probably gave me the most help asked my version numbers for Node and Stormpath, and when I gave them, he said that my version number from my package.json didn't look like a stormpath-express version number.

What I found out in trying to reconcile is that there are both a **stormpath-express** package, and an **express-stormpath** package, and the "that's odd" remark I got was when I he asked me my version number with *stormpath-express* in mind, and I answered him with the *express-stormpath* from my packages.json.

I don't know how little or how much this had to do with my original troubles in [What do I need to know to transfer a working Node project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319150/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-transfer-a-working-node-project?noredirect=1#comment52519790_32319150), but what is the difference between **stormpath-express** and **express-stormpath**, and which package do I want to use for (for a Node.js + Express.js + Stormpath) application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heyo -- I'm the author of these libraries, so let me help clarify things.

The library you want to use (without fail!) is this: express-stormpath: https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath

The github repo is named 'stormpath-express' (due to a company naming convention), but the library is called 'express-stormpath', and it is the one you want to use.

We just made a new release of this library which supports EVERYTHING -- angular included. So you'll want to use this library now, and for the future =)

Answer (score 0):

See the new configuration options here:

https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath/blob/master/lib/config.yml

Comment: Please add a summary of what one might find if they followed the link. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [ask]